# Why is the number of OTC securites different between OTC Markets and FINRA?

Tags: united-states, stocks, penny-stocks, pink-sheets, over-the-counter

According to OTC Markets (https://www.otcmarkets.com/research/stock-screener), there are currently 16,610 quoted securities on its system :

[image: OTC Markets stock screener]

However, according to FINRA (https://otce.finra.org/otce/directories), there are 16,524 OTC securities that FINRA knows of:

[image: FINRA OTCBB symbol directory]

What explains the difference (16,610 for OTC Markets vs. 16,524 for FINRA)? From my understanding, all ticker symbols come from FINRA. Doesn't FINRA know about every ticker in existence? Why the discrepancy?

Comment: Have you considered the possibility that they don't update in real time?  There might be a lag in the  recordkeeping of one of them?  If you really want to know the answer, download both list and remove all duplicates.  Then look up some of the 86 stock differential and see whether they are new additions or late deletions. AFAIC, this would be a nothing burger to me unless a stock that I was interested in wasn't showing up.

Comment: The data in OTC Markets' stock screener is sometimes incorrect (e.g. [What is the difference between ADRs and New York Registry Shares?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/126915/what-is-the-difference-between-adrs-and-new-york-registry-shares)).